# Set null value of attribute if include doesn't find any relational data in sequelize

Tags: node.js, json, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find out the books where one book can have multiple banners.

So I have applied relation of has many banners while finding the books.

It is working fine but I want response to be different if in case book don't have any banner.

```
Book.findAll({
                order: [
                    ['updated_at', 'ASC']
                ],
                attributes: {
                    exclude: ["thumbnail", "listenTime", "created_at", "today_book_day"],
                },
                include: [{
                        model: banner,
                        as: 'banners',
                        attributes: [
                            [banner_attribute, 'url']
                        ],
                        where: whereAttribute,
                        required: false
                    }
                ]
            }).then(books => {
                var totalPage = 1;
                if (totalBooks){
                    totalPage = Math.ceil(totalBooks / pagesize);
                }
                var metaInfo = {
                    currentPage: parseInt(page),
                    totalPage: totalPage,
                    pagesize: pagesize
                };
                var output = {
                    'meta': metaInfo,
                    "data": books,
                    "status": 200
                };
                res.send(output);
            });
```

Getting the response like below :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalPage": 3,
        "pagesize": 100
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 114,
            "rating": "5.00",
            "like": -1,
            "comment": 0,
            "listen": 49,
            "category": "[]",
            "order": 9,
            "updated_at": 1589475237,
            "thumbnailUrl": null,
            "banners": []
        },
        "status": 200
    ]
}
```

But I want the JSON response like below :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalPage": 3,
        "pagesize": 100
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 114,
            "rating": "5.00",
            "like": -1,
            "comment": 0,
            "listen": 49,
            "category": "[]",
            "order": 9,
            "updated_at": 1589475237,
            "thumbnailUrl": null,
            "banners": [
                {
                    "url" : null
                }
            ],
        },
        "status": 200
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid JSON

```
"banners": [url" : null] // table of... what?
```

I assume you want something like this?

```
"banners": [ {"url" : null} ] // table with one object, which has key 'url' and value 'null'
```

But if banners array is empty, then you can conclude url is null. You don't need to put this information explicitly.

Comment: Alright the JSON was invalid and I have fix that. But coming to the desired response this is the requirement of android developer that response should be like this.

Comment: If so, then I think you have to add some logic (eg. in controller) to change that response  before sending it.